# For Vue 2/3, when using provide/inject to provide a function from an ancestor component, how can that function access the ancestor's properties?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an ancestor Vue 2 component that uses `provide`/`inject` to inject a function from the ancestor to any nested (descendant) component.  However I'm finding that inside that function `this` is not bound to the ancestor but to the descendant.

**How can I get a reference the ancestor from inside the injected function `onCallback()` ?**

Example:

```html
<template>
  <Intermediary />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Ancestor",
  props: ["val"],
  provide: {
    onCallback() {
      console.log(this.val); // <<< fails as `this` is bound to caller component
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <Descendant />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Intermediary"
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <button @click="onCallback">Click Me!</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Descendant",
  inject["onCallback"]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mre]? And may I know why don't you use `$emit` and listen it on parent instead?

Comment: I  can't use this.$emit() as the descendant is deeply nested (ancestor is in fact 2 or more levels higher) and $this.$root.emit() is too high up (won't have access to the props.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function syntax to access `this`, import `computed` at the top and re-write `provide` like:

```
provide() {
  return {
    onCallback: computed(() => () => console.log(this.val))
  }
}
```

Do note that using function syntax doesn't make injected variables reactive by default. You need to use `computed` to make them reactive. I highly recommend to go through this [official doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) to understand the concept correctly.

Working example: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: I tried this practice but `this` is `undefined`. Arrow function is not working. Please check suggested edit answer since Vue SFC playground sharable link is too long

Comment: If I'm able to reference `this` inside the Provide() function that we can assigned it to a local `self` variable and us that inside `onCallback()`

Comment: Edited and added a working example.

Comment: @HuyPhạm - You hadn't used `provide` as a function in your VUE SFC, thats why you were getting `this` as `undefined`. I reposted your SFC playground link with working changes.

Comment: Thank you! I may have slightly different constraints (it's an old legacy HTML/jQuery app retro fitted to use Vue 2) so hopefully I can still use this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I originally missed was that `provide()` can be a function that is always bound to the ancestor component. I don't need to use `computed()`.

```html
<template>
  <Intermediary />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Ancestor",
  props: ["val"],
  provide() {
    return {
      onCallback() {
        console.log(this.val); 
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```